# Does app will be removed in installed phones if the app unpublished from AppStore?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

I have an app which is in live (Published in AppStore). Now if I would removed that app from AppStore ,can that app still able to use in already installed phones?

Or is there anyway to do the same by other way? I wanted that my app cant used by anyone even they have installed it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What's your end goal?

Comment: No, you can't remove an app from people's phones or stop it from working (unless it depends on a server that you can shut down). Apple probably can, but they won't except in extreme circumstances because of the PR impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, removing your app from the App Store won't remove it from other people's devices (iPhones/iPads).

Yes, an app that was removed from the App Store but is still installed on a user's device. If the app relies on data from another server (getting data from a database or a news source) an this data cannot be accessed anymore at least parts of the app won'be functional anymore.